# Writing a batch file to move cluttered files into respective folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch file code which when run in a folder, checks the file extension, creates the folder against the file extension and finally moves the file into folder name with extension name i.e. it will create `.gif` folder to move all gifs into it and `.jpg` folder to move all jpg's into it and so on.

I have no expertise in writing a batch file but all I need is to change this code in such a way that all file may go into the folders in such a way that all image file should go in "Images" folder, all video files in "Videos", all documents files (pdf,docs,xls etc.) in Docs folder, all Audio files should be in Audio folder and so on......
Can anybody help???

```
@echo off
rem For each file in your folder
for %%a in (".\*") do (
rem check if the file has an extension and if it is not our script
if "%%~xa" NEQ ""  if "%%~dpxa" NEQ "%~dpx0" (
rem check if extension folder exists, if not it is created
if not exist "%%~xa" mkdir "%%~xa"
rem Move the file to directory
move "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\"
))
```

@compo The file types with respect to categories are as follows: -

```
Docs
   .docs,docx,xls,pdf
Video
   .avi,.mpeg,.mp4
Audio
   .mp3,.wma
Image
   .jpg,.bmp,.gif
```

and so on......

The category name should actually the folder name.

Comment: To do that, you would have to provide a listing of file types with categories as pairs in a text file to read along side your script. Something along the lines of `Documents,.docx` and `Pictures,.psd` etc. each entry on a different line. _(separate each pair with a comma)_. When you've created your list post it here as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46502116/edit) to your question and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your listing is small you could probably just add the information to your script file instead of a separate file:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/B : %0'
) Do @RoboCopy/MOV . "%%A"%%B>Nul
@Exit/B

:Docs: *.doc *.docx *.xls *.pdf
:Video: *.avi *.mpeg *.mp4
:Audio: *.mp3 *.wma
:Image: *.jpg *.bmp *.gif
```

Edit the last four lines as necessary, *it should be self-explanatory to do so*.

**Edit**

Using a separate file, **FileCats.txt**:

```bat
Docs: *.doc *.docx *.xls *.pdf
Video: *.avi *.mpeg *.mp4
Audio: *.mp3 *.wma
Image: *.jpg *.bmp *.gif
```

...and the batch file, **Categorise.cmd**:

```bat
@For /F "UseBackQTokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ("FileCats.txt"
) Do @RoboCopy/MOV . "%%A"%%B>Nul
```

*Make sure there's a space after the **`:`***

Comment: Thanks a lot. From your words I can understand that we can read a file in a batch file. Is it true?? If this code has to be changed with respect to reading file types from a file, how would it be??

Comment: Added separate file version as **Edit**

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for %%s in (Images Videos Docs Audio) do md .\%%s 2>nul

rem For each file in your folder
for %%a in (".\*") do (
 set "moved="
 rem check if the file has an extension and if it is not our script
 if "%%~xa" NEQ ""  if "%%~dpxa" NEQ "%~dpx0" (

  for %%s in (pdf doc xls) do if /i "%%~xa"==".%%s" set "moved=Y"&move "%%a" ".\Docs\"
  for %%s in (mpg avi) do if /i "%%~xa"==".%%s" set "moved=Y"&move "%%a" ".\Videos\"
  IF NOT DEFINED moved (

   rem check if extension folder exists, if not it is created
   if not exist "%%~xa" mkdir "%%~xa"
   rem Move the file to directory
   move "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\"

  )

 )
)
```

Note : `MD ... 2>nul` suppresses the error message when the directory can't be created (because it already exists)

First, create the directories to hold the collections.

For each file, first set `moved` to *nothing* (ie. "clear" it so it's *undefined*)

Then check the extension in a case-insensitive manner (/i) against a list of extensions to be placed in the collection. If you find a match, set `moved` to some value (like `Y`) and move to the appropriate collection. After all collection lists have ben examined, if `moved` is still`*nothing* (ie *not defined*) then move the file to the directory as determined by the extension.

(untested)

Comment: I have amended it to my needs but I have not expertise in writing a batch file, so not up to the mark as I really want. I have managed a little though. Thanks for the help.